# Firebase realtime database and Cloud Functions locations and speed

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I have a Firebase realtime database project that was originally created on the central1 server (USA).

The problem is that the applications using this database and the Cloud Functions related are all used in Europe (mainly France). Someone in the same situation changed the server to "europe-west1" and noticed a big improvement in term of speed for the Cloud Functions.

So I have several questions : will it really affect the speed? And also, do I have to change both the database and the Cloud Functions locations to make it work smoothly?

It is easy to change the Cloud Functions locations but it seems not possible to change the location of a realtime database once it is created.

I am afraid having a database located in USA and the Cloud Functions running from Europe would be even worse...

Answer (score 0):

According to the Cloud Functions [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/locations#background_functions) the region recommended to deploy the Cloud Function if they are triggered by or uses a Realtime Database is always US-Central1.

An alternative to provide a better experience for the non-us users could be implementing a small function in the EU zone for all the non database related job that later connects to the Cloud Functions that does all the job related to the database.